# Nginx/Fcgi: index.php issue with pseudo-alias location

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

*Nginx 1.6.2 on Debian Jessie*

I want to map all **example.com/forum/** requests to **/path/to/htdocs/phpbb** and cut off the */forum/* part in the URI. Someone on Stackoverflow recommended the *"rewrite"* solution instead of *"alias"*, because there are some bugs.

```
server
{
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location /forum/
    {
        root /path/to/htdocs/phpbb;
        rewrite ^/forum/(.*)$ /$1 break;

        location ~ .+\.php$
        {
            rewrite ^/forum/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

The example configuration works fine – **example.com/forum/viewtopic.php** executes the script **/path/to/htdocs/phpbb/viewtopic.php** – but **example.com/** (*index.php*) doesn't work:

> "/var/www/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory)

After removing the *"index"* line from server block:

> directory index of "/path/to/htdocs/phpbb/" is forbidden

After moving the *"index"* and/or *"try_files"* line(s) into the location block:

> index.php served without passing over to php-fpm…

Ok, what's wrong with my config? Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, alias is buggy (*rewrite* too…), but if you avoid *try_files* and use if instead (even if evil…) it should work!

```
server
{
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/html;

    location /forum/
    {
        alias /path/to/htdocs/phpbb/;
        index index.php index.html;

        location ~ "^(/forum/)(.+\.php)(/.+){0,1}$"
        {
            if (!-f $document_root$2)
            {
                return 404;
            }

            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;

            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$2;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $1$2;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $3;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

phpinfo() looks fine, but one question remains: **Is it secure?**